# Exception logging HttpModule doesn't catch errors from ASP .NET Page Method

Tags: asp.net, webforms

We have an HttpModule that is designed to catch exceptions and log them to the db. It looks something like this:

```
public class ExceptionLoggingModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.Error += OnError;
    }

    private static void OnError(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var context = (HttpApplication) sender;
            var exception = context.Server.GetLastError();

            if (exception != null)
            {
                // Log exception
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This works in general, but I've just noticed that the OnError method never fires when an error occurs within *Page Methods* (i.e. methods in a code behind file marked with the WebMethod attribute).

How come?

Is there something I can do about this, other than reimplementing the exception logging inside the Page Method itself?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem today.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that worked for me here:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/oshvartz/archive/2008/05/17/asp-net-error-handling-using-httpmodule-full-and-partial-post-back-ajax-updatepanel.aspx

Here's the key points of the handler I've written:

```
public class PathfinderModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PostMapRequestHandler += this.OnPostMapRequestHandler;
        context.Error += OnError;
    }

    private void OnPostMapRequestHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page aux = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;

        if (aux != null)
        {
            aux.Error += this.OnPageError;
        }
    }

    private static void OnError(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Blah..
    }

    private void OnPageError(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Blah...
    }        
}
```

Comment: Hm this doesn't work from me - if I throw an exception from inside a PageMethod, the event handler doesn't fire.

Comment: Part1: Check the basics - web.config contains the right settings and those settings are formatted/spelled correctly (I've been caught out this a few times). Restart IIS/app pool just to be sure. Place a breakpoint inside the `Init()` method and attach Visual Studio to the w3wp.exe process which is hosting your site. You want to know that the code is executing

Comment: Part 2: If the attch method doesn't work, then put some `Trace.WriteLine()` calls in the code so that you can see if that code is being called. Use a tool like DebugOutput from Sysinternals to pick up the WriteLine calls. If your code is not executing at all, then I'm not sure what it could be, sorry.

Comment: Hi thanks, with all the necessary breakpoints I can see it is executing when exceptions are raised during the normal Page lifecycle, but not when raised by PageMethods.

Comment: OK, it might be worth you opening a new question, with a reference to this question, and post the code you are using. Sounds like you may have a different issue then what I suffered. Will make it easier to help you if you discuss it in its own question.